# map <BS> to behave differently in vim

Tags: vim, keymapping

[image]

I want pressing backspace to result in:

[image]

For references

doing just x or just dl produces

[image]

and dh gives

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <BS> x
```

This adds a non-recursive mapping to normal mode, where `<BS>` now performs `x`.

If you just want to test this mapping without adding it to your `.vimrc`, enter command mode with `:` , type in the line above, then hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

you can map `<BS>` to do `x` and then `h`:

```
nnoremap <BS> xh
```

This should be what you are looking for.

### update, handle the EOL case:

```
nnoremap <expr> <BS> col('.')==(col('$')-1)?'x':'xh'
```

Comment: I wonder if what I want is truly possible, so this works with one exception. If the character deleted is the last character of a line then it moves to the left twice. This is because first it does x which deletes the character but now there is no character so it moves left, then it does the h which moves it left again but in this case we do not want that.